# switch perl process to background after user input

Tags: perl

Problem Statement --

I display a message to user using Perl and takes an input.On the basis of input I decide whether I need to do further processing or not.This processing takes a long time ( say 5 hour) and user run this process by logging into remote Unix/Linux system.Hence to make sure that network malfunctioning will not affect the process; I want to switch the process to background.

How can I switch such running Perl process to background?

or

Is it possible to take user input from current terminal( the terminal from where user run process as input need to be taken at very starting) if process is running into background?

OS - Linux variants

Comment: Use two scripts - or a single script with two modes.  One for collecting user input, the other for processing.  With command line args, this can actually be in a single script that runs a copy of itself, in the background, after collecting the users input.

Comment: @Jim Black -- I could not get your point. Can you please elaborate if the solution differ than the already provided solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very, very simple example for my comment above...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $lcnt = 0;
if( !$ARGV[0] ) {  # If no ARGS on the command line, get user input
    print "How many lines do you want to print?";
    chomp( $lcnt = <STDIN> );
    if( $lcnt > 0 ) {
        # when we are sure we have what we need
        # call myself.pl and put it in the background with '&'
        my $cmd = "./myself.pl ".$lcnt.' &';
        system($cmd);
        exit(0);
    } else { die "Invalid input!\n"; }
} else {  # Otherwise, lets do the processing
    $lcnt = $ARGV[0];
    for( my $x = 0; $x <= $lcnt; $x++ ) {
        my $cmd = "echo 'Printing line: $lcnt' >> /tmp/myself.txt";
        system($cmd);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
exit(0);
```

If you save this to a file called 'myself.pl' then run it.  With no arguments on the command line, the script will ask you to input a number.  Type in 20 and press enter.  You'll see the script exit almost instantly.  But if you quickly

```
tail -f /tmp/myself.txt
```

you'll see that the background process is still running, printing a new line to the file every second.  Also, typing the 'ps' command on Linux systems, should show the spawned process running in the background:

```
jlb@linux-f7r2:~/test> ps
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1243 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 4171 pts/1    00:00:00 myself.pl
 4176 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Answer (score 4):

Yup, you want to daemonize your program after it finishes its interaction with the user. I would encourage you to use a module like [`Proc::Daemon`](http://search.cpan.org/~deti/Proc-Daemon-0.14/) to do the work, though: there are a bunch of subtleties in doing it correctly. The [POD for `Proc::Daemon`](http://search.cpan.org/~deti/Proc-Daemon-0.14/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod) gives a good description of its usage, but a simple usage can be as basic as

```
use Proc::Daemon;

# ... finished the interactive stuff
my $pid = Proc::Daemon::Init( { work_dir => '/var/run/my_program' })
exit 0 if ($pid == 0);
die "Error daemonizing, cannot continue: $!\n" if ($! != 0);
# ... now do the background processing
# note that STDOUT and STDERR are no longer connected to the user's terminal!
```

Answer (score 2):

Demonise the process if the correct input:

```
#test input
if($inputsuccess) {
    if(fork() = 0) {
        #child
        if(fork() = 0) {
            #child
            #background processing
        }
    } else {
       wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- fork() create identical child. Then how this child will run in background?
2- It seems me that due to network malfunctioning parent process can get aborted. So child will become orphan?

Comment: The child becomes an orphan so that the shell detects that the process terminated causing the orphan process to run the background

Comment: This answer is correct but horribly incomplete. Basically, if you fork once and then exit the parent, the child process that is spawned becomes a "zombie" because it doesn't have anyone to report to but its parent has an open terminal session so it COULD have a terminal one day. So you have that process spawn a grandchild, and then wait() for the child to exit. The child will exit cleanly and the abandoned grand-child process will be handed off to the OS as an orphan since its parent never had ownership of a terminal. In effect you're tricking OS into running a process in the background.

Comment: virus see Marks comment, it is essential to have both forks and the wait

Comment: This answer is also correct.ofcourse system() will invoke fork() at the lowest level.I don't have option to select two answers.