# How to continue Perl script execution in background?

Tags: perl, unix, fork, zombie-process

I have a script in which I'd like to add an "auto" mode where it will do
some processing, generate  some output, and then enter  in background by
itself.

How can I achieve  this safely? Would a simple fork  and exit the parent
do it, or would this generate a zombie (orphan) problem?

```
# initial processing
defined (my $pid fork) or die "Can't fork: $!";
exit if $pid;
# continue child in background
```

Comment: Orphans, i.e. processes where the parent is no longer there, are usually automatically reaped by the init process. Zombies are a different thing: there the parent process exists but does not care to `wait` for the child and thus the process is not fully reaped even if it is dead. In your case this would be orphans, so no need to worry about this part. You might need to worry about shared file descriptors etc with the parent of the parent (i.e. shell).

Comment: As stated, this is safe.  It is one way to put something in the background -- fork and exit in the parent immediately, while the code to run is in the child.  Then the init takes over the child and all is well (will eventually reap it, when the child finishes). What do you want the child to do then? Is it somehow related to the initial processing that is done in the parent before it exits?

Comment: Thanks @zdim . Yes, related. Well, I'm calling it just a new mode to run the same thing. In its "normal" mode the script fetches data, outputs a summary of what will be done, and then outputs what is being done in each step. I already implemented a silent mode, but I find the summary to be particularly useful. So this new "mode" would run until the summary is printed, then if the new option was given do a fork, kill the parent, set to silent and continue execution. Hopefully this is a good way to implement it.

Comment: OK, thanks. You can restart that same program in the child as a deamon, running it with the option to not do that initial summary part.  That may simplify the code altogether.  A good way to make it a deamon is by  [Proc::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~akreal/Proc-Daemon-0.23/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod).  There is good info on a seemingly very similar idea in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646694/running-job-in-the-background-from-perl-without-waiting-for-return) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186436/switch-perl-process-to-background-after-user-input).

Comment: Also, [this perlmonks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=41683) rehashes [code from perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Complete-Dissociation-of-Child-from-Parent) to daemonize a process (no modules).

Comment: @zdim thank you very much for the links and information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orphans, i.e. processes where the parent is no longer there, are usually automatically reaped by the init process. Zombies are a different thing: there the parent process exists but does not care to `wait` for the child and thus the process is not fully reaped even if it is dead. In your case this would be orphans, so no need to worry about this part.

You might still need to worry about shared file descriptors etc with the parent of the parent in case you've executed your process from a shell. I recommend that you also close all file descriptors but especially stdin, stderr and stdout.

Comment: Considering that in normal execution my script wouldn't close stdin et all, I'm wondering if this child would really need to do it after its creation. Am I'm missing something?

Comment: @sidyll: this is probably only relevant if you start a script from an interactive shell and don't want to have any trouble from bad interactions with the shell, i.e. like the shell stopping the script if it writes to stdout etc. There are a couple of other pitfalls in this area like inferring the shells job control. I've often seen double fork combined with closing of the std* fd to fully detach from the shell.